# Add one image onto another with scaling easily

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've got the following problem: I have a box retrieved from `minAreaRect`

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
```

And I would like to fit a rectangular image there, scaling that so it would take the shape of the box. How do I do that?

Well, I know that we can create a 2 arrays one `[[0, 0], [0, height], [width, height], [width, 0]]` and another one with the box coordinates, then use `getPerspectiveTransform` and `warpPerspective`. But is there a simpler and probably faster way for doing that?

I'm using OpenCV 2.4

Comment: Well. you can use an _affine_ transform, which is _simpler_ than a _perspective_ transform. Faster? Have you profiled it? Surely, this approach is the easiest to code. Any other approach should somehow deal directly with translation, rotation and scaling... That's just an affine transform...